# awk: format date string from YYYYMMDD to YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: linux, string, bash, awk, format

I have a `CSV` file which I parse using `awk` because I don't need all columns.
The problem I have is that one column is a date but in the format `YYYYMMDD` but I need it in `YYYY-MM-DD` and I don't know how to achieve that.

I already tried with `split($27, a)` but it doesn't split it - so `a[0]` returns the whole string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`substr`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html):

```
printf "%s-%s-%s", substr($27,0,4), substr($27,5,2), substr($27,7,2)
```

Assuming that the 27<sup>th</sup> field was `20140318`, this would produce `2014-03-18`.

Answer (score 4):

Use your `awk` output as input to `date -d`, e.g.

```
$ date -d 20140918 +'%Y-%m-%d'
2014-09-18
```